# Evenly space absolutely positioned elements in a flexbox container

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, alignment

When using flexbox on an element with absolutely positioned children - the child elements seem to adhere to the `justify-content` and `align-items` rules if the values are set to `center`. Like in the snippet below:

```css
* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
html { overflow: hidden; font-size: 0.7rem; }
body { font-family: Arial; }
section, div {
  display: flex;             /* Even though the child is absolutely positioned */
  justify-content: center;   /* The child is centered horizontally */
  align-items: center;       /* ...and the child is centered vertically */
  border-radius: 1rem; 
}
h2, section {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: #444;
}
section {
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}
div {
  position: absolute; /* absolutely positioned child adheres to flexbox rules */
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.75 );
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>Flex-box Parent &amp; Absolutely Positioned Child</h2>
<section class='flex-parent'>
  <div>50%</div>
</section>
```

**Flexbox rules seem to affect the child even though it is absolutely positioned as long as our flexbox values are `center`.**

However when our flexbox values are something else, like `space-between` or `space-around` - the absolutely positioned elements seem to completely ignore these flexbox rules. Like below:

```css
* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
html { overflow: hidden; font-size: 0.6125rem; }
body { font-family: Arial; }
section, div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* the positioned children ignore 'space-between'*/
  align-items: center;            /* the elements are just stacked on eachother */
  border-radius: 1rem;            /* in the second section */
}
h2, section {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: #444;
}
section {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}
div {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 5rem; height: 5rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.75 );
  color: #eee;
}
.absolute-parent { height: 5rem; }
.absolute-parent div { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<h2>Flex-box Parent</h2>
<section class='flex-parent'>
  <div>0%</div>
  <div>25%</div>
  <div>75%</div>
  <div>100%</div>
</section>

<h2>Absolutely Positioned Children</h2>
<section class='absolute-parent'>
  <div>0%</div>
  <div>25%</div>
  <div>75%</div>
  <div>100%</div>
</section>
```

### How do I make the children in the second `section` element space evenly in their container?

Comment: It’s not ignoring anything. You have them set to absolute so they are all stacked on top of eachother and acting as the first element in the flex container. It looks like space-between isn’t doing anything but in reality it is. With space-between the first element aligns at the start of the container so it is where it should be. Unfortunately they all think they are first. Try flex-end or space-evenly they will move (all together of course).

Comment: @Justin You are correct that space-evenly and flex-end have an effect on the child elements. However, because they are absolutely positioned they are still all stacked on top of each other in one location. This question is asking how we can override this behavior and place them equal distances apart.

Comment: Not sure it’s possible. Maybe there is some trick to get it done but I don’t know it. From reading the docs it doesn’t sound like you can. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items

Comment: @Justin *You might be right that it's not possible.* I tried using `display: grid` and changing the position values on the parent element to no avail. The question is then - how do we **manually** position items at 25% or 75% width and so on. `transform: translateX( -50% ); left: 50%;` horizontally centers an item perfectly but what formula can we use to get something exactly a quarter or a 3rd of the way from the edge? `transform: translateX( -25% ); left: 25%` doesn't put an element anywhere close to a quarter. Any ideas?

Comment: Once you start applying positioning a to an absolutely positioned element within a flex container you remove it from the flex. It is now being positioned in relation to the body. In order to position them within the flex container still it would require doing some math to account for the window.innerWidth and the container size etc etc.

Comment: You would need to add an actual position property: left, right, top, bottom. So if you have four elements in your absolutely positioned element, place a relative position to its parent and then add a percentage for each element within that parent. Gets dicey that way though...